# How to store a variable after form closes for use later on another form

Tags: vb.net, forms, return-value

So I am building a form based application, and I am running into an issue with passing data between forms.  I have a combo box that, based on selection, triggers a new form to open with several buttons to pick from.  Once you select a button, the form closes, but I can't get the selection to be carried over to the original form.

basic idea of the code is like this

```
Public Class frmMain

    Public intStore As integer

    Private Sub cboSample_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboSample.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim selection as Integer
        selection = cboSample.SelectedIndex

        If selection = -1 Then
        Else
            Select Case selection
                Case 0
                    frmOne.Show()
                Case 1
                    frmTwo.Show()
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is a sample of the second form code

```
Public Class frmOne
    Public storage As varStorage

    Private Sub btn_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Clicked
        storage = New varStorage With {.datastore = 1}
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

frmTwo is pretty much the same but handles more options

The Class I created looks like this

```
Public Class varStorage
    Public _dataStore As Integer

    Public Property dataStore() As Integer
        Get 
            Return _dataStore
        End Get
        Set (value As Integer)
            _dataStore = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

as I said, the issue comes from the point of the form being called, and the form closing, the variable data is not being saved.  I am almost certain I am missing some code somewhere, but not sure where.  any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider ShowDialog() instead, now you know that the user closed the form.

Comment: You might also want to learn about form instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using Show() to open another form, using ShowDialog() will open the form modally. The form will behave like a MessageBox. It will wait for you to respond to, and close, this form before returning to your main form. We can obtain a value from this modal-form, safe in the knowledge that the form has been closed (and so the value we have obtained will not be changed).

The other way is to make a Public Property of the form. then you can create Get and Set methods to have access to your form objects

```
Public Class yourFormClass
  Public Property Note As String
    Get
        Return txtNote.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)

    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

and Then you can use it like

```
dialog = New yourFormClass()
someOtherTextbox.Text = dialog.Note
```